# eclipselink/jpa inheritance problems

Tags: sql, spring-boot, jpa, inheritance, eclipselink

I am using spring boot (2.0.0) with eclipse link to persist data (over 500 entity classes) to a postgres db (6.5). Thats works very well. For receiving the data over REST I build an other spring boot application. Here I have some inheriance problem with JPA (sorry for my drawing):

[image]

Class C and class D (abstract) inherit from class B. Class A have a reference (attribute1) to class B. This attribute is an instance of entity class E, which inherit from abstract class D. I am using inheritance strategy table per class. Every class using the annotation Entity with the table name. In the database, table from class A have a correct foreign key to table from class E, but if I want to read the data the attribute1 is null. I see from the log level that eclipse link only look inside table from class C. How can I resolve this problem?

Greets Benjamin

Comment: It works if I remove abstract from class d

Comment: and get the error if I remove @entity annotation from class d: uses a non-entity ... as target entity in the relationship attribute... because in an other class I have a reference on it

Comment: Why not show the A and B classes/mappings? You also start by stating you are able to persist this data to the database using EclipseLink - how is it mapped there and if it works, why not use that here too?

Comment: @Chris Sorry for the missunderstanding I can persist this classes into the database, but I cannot retrieve this class over eclipselink. In my datamodel:  class A  have a private field (attribute 1) of type class B. I dont want change the data model because it is a standard.

Comment: You still need to show the classes and mappings for us to help point out what might be going wrong with it.

Answer (score 0):

here are the classes, class E:

```
@Entity(name="ep_core_voltagelevel")

public class VoltageLevel extends EquipmentContainer {

@Embedded

@AttributeOverrides(@AttributeOverride(name="value", column=@Column(name="highVoltageLimit_value")
)
)

private myPackage.DomainProfile.Voltage highVoltageLimit;

public myPackage.DomainProfile.Voltage getHighVoltageLimit()  {
return highVoltageLimit;
}

public void setHighVoltageLimit(myPackage.DomainProfile.Voltage parameter)  {
this.highVoltageLimit = parameter;
}

@Embedded

@AttributeOverrides(@AttributeOverride(name="value", column=@Column(name="lowVoltageLimit_value")
)
)

private myPackage.DomainProfile.Voltage lowVoltageLimit;

public myPackage.DomainProfile.Voltage getLowVoltageLimit()  {
return lowVoltageLimit;
}

public void setLowVoltageLimit(myPackage.DomainProfile.Voltage parameter)  {
this.lowVoltageLimit = parameter;
}

@ManyToOne(cascade={CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REFRESH})

@JoinColumn(nullable=false, name="basevoltage_id")

private BaseVoltage baseVoltage;

public BaseVoltage getBaseVoltage()  {
return baseVoltage;
}

public void setBaseVoltage(BaseVoltage parameter)  {
this.baseVoltage = parameter;
}

@ManyToOne(cascade={CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REFRESH})

@JoinColumn(nullable=false, name="substation_id")

private Substation substation;

public Substation getSubstation()  {
return substation;
}

public void setSubstation(Substation parameter)  {
this.substation = parameter;
}
}
```

Class D:

```
@Entity(name = "ep_core_equipmentcontainer")
public abstract class EquipmentContainer extends ConnectivityNodeContainer {
}
```

Class B:

```
@Entity(name="ep_core_connectivitynodecontainer")
public abstract class ConnectivityNodeContainer extends PowerSystemResource {
}
```

Class A:

```
public class ConnectivityNode extends IdentifiedObject {

    @ManyToOne(cascade={CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REFRESH})

    @JoinColumn(nullable=false, name="connectivitynodecontainer_id")

    private ConnectivityNodeContainer connectivityNodeContainer;

    public ConnectivityNodeContainer getConnectivityNodeContainer()  {
        return connectivityNodeContainer;
    }

    public void setConnectivityNodeContainer(ConnectivityNodeContainer parameter)  {
        this.connectivityNodeContainer = parameter;
    }
}
```